# Is it possible to download invoices from AWS billing using the sdk-for-java and if so, how?

Tags: java, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I've been looking at the documentation for the [AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html) and I'm trying to find  how one can download the monthly invoices using this SDK. Is it at all possible or am I chasing my tail here?

If this is not supported, are there any alternatives I could use?